# python code for vcard duplicate removal in vcf file works with vobject but only for "exact duplicates"

Tags: python-2.7, duplicates, vcf-vcard, vobject

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7 

import vobject

abinfile='/foo/bar/dir/infile.vcf' #ab stands for address book  

aboutfile='/foo/bar/dir/outfile.vcf'  

def eliminate_vcard_duplicates (abinfile, aboutfile):

    #we first convert the Adrees Book IN FILE into a list

    with open(abinfile) as source_file:
        ablist = list(vobject.readComponents(source_file))

    #then add each vcard from that list in a new list unless it's already there

    ablist_norepeats=[]
    ablist_norepeats.append(ablist[0])

    for i in range(1, len(ablist)):
        jay=len(ablist_norepeats)
        for j in reversed(range(0, jay)): #we do reversed because usually cards have duplicates nearby
            if ablist_norepeats[j].serialize() == ablist[i].serialize():
                break
            else:
                jay += -1
        if jay == 0:
            ablist_norepeats.append(ablist[i])

    #and finally write the singularized list to the Adrees Book OUT FILE

    with open(aboutfile, 'w') as destination_file:
        for j in range(0, len(ablist_norepeats)):
            destination_file.write(ablist_norepeats[j].serialize)

eliminate_vcard_duplicates(abinfile, aboutfile)
```

The above code works and creates a new file where there are no exact duplicates (duplicates with identical singularizations). I know the code has some efficiency issues: it's n square, when it could be n*log n; we could serialize each vacard only once; inefficient use of for etc. Here I wanted to provide a short code to illustrate one of the issues I don't know how to solve.

The issue that I'm not sure how to solve elegantly is this one: If *some of* the fields in the cards are scrambled it will not detect they are equal. Is there a way to detect such duplicates either with vobject, re, or another approach?

The file contents used in the test, with four equal vcards (phones scrambled messes up code - not email scrambled thought), is this one:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Foo_bar1
N:;Foo_bar1;;;
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:foobar1@foo.bar.com
TEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789
TEL;TYPE=CELL:987654321
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Foo_bar1
N:;Foo_bar1;;;
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:foobar1@foo.bar.com
TEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789
TEL;TYPE=CELL:987654321
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Foo_bar1
N:;Foo_bar1;;;
TEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789
TEL;TYPE=CELL:987654321
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:foobar1@foo.bar.com
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Foo_bar1
N:;Foo_bar1;;;
TEL;TYPE=CELL:987654321
TEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:foobar1@foo.bar.com
END:VCARD
```

The above code will not detect that the four are all the same because the last one has the phone numbers scrambled.

As bonus points, if someone has a faster algorithm it would be great if it can be shared. The above one takes days on a 30.000 Vcard file...

Answer (score 2):

One thing you might have noticed is that if you call the
`.serialize()` method then `EMAIL` is sorted before `FN`. But
unfortunately the telefonenumbers are not sorted. If they were, you
could add the serialized individual components to a set, and let the
unique hashes sort out the multiple occurences.

If you investigate what you get from the generator
`vobject.readComponents()` (e.g. using `type()`), you'll see that that
is a `Component` from the module `vobject.base`, and using `dir()` on
an instance you see a method `getSortedChildren()`. If you look that
up in the source, you'll find:

```
def getSortedChildren(self):
    return [obj for k in self.sortChildKeys() for obj in self.contents[k]]
```

and `sortChildKeys()` a directly above that:

```
def sortChildKeys(self):
    try:
        first = [s for s in self.behavior.sortFirst if s in self.contents]
    except Exception:
        first = []
    return first + sorted(k for k in self.contents.keys() if k not in first)
```

calling `sortChildKeys()` on your example instances gives `['version',
'email', 'fn', 'n', 'tel']`, which leads to two conclusions:

- `sortFirst` causes `version` to be at the front
- `for obj in self.contents[k]` is not sorted therefore your TEL entries are not sorted.

The solution seems to be that you redefine `getSortedChildren()` to:

```
    return [obj for k in self.sortChildKeys() for obj in sorted(self.contents[k])]
```

but that leads to:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ContentLine' and 'ContentLine'

so you need to provide some basic comparison operations for
`ContentLine` which is also defined in `vobject.base` as well:

```
import vobject

from vobject.base import Component, ContentLine

def gsc(self):
    return [obj for k in self.sortChildKeys() for obj in sorted(self.contents[k])]

Component.getSortedChildren = gsc

def ltContentLine(self, other):
    return str(self) < str(other)

def eqContentLine(self, other):
    return str(self) == str(other)

ContentLine.__lt__ = ltContentLine
ContentLine.__eq__ = eqContentLine


addresses = set()
with open('infile.vcf') as fp:
  for vcard in vobject.readComponents(fp):
     # print(type(vcard))
     # print(dir(vcard))
     # print(vcard.sortChildKeys())
     # print(vcard.contents.keys())
     addresses.add(vcard.serialize())

with open('outfile.vcf', 'w') as fp:
    for a in addresses:
        fp.write(a)

# and check
with open('outfile.vcf') as fp:
    print(fp.read(), end="")
```

which gives:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:foobar1@foo.bar.com
FN:Foo_bar1
N:;Foo_bar1;;;
TEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789
TEL;TYPE=CELL:987654321
END:VCARD
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a faster code (about three orders of magnitude) but still does only remove exact duplicates...

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2.7 

    import vobject
    import datetime

    abinfile='/foo/bar/dir/infile.vcf' #ab stands for address book  

    aboutfile='/foo/bar/dir/outfile.vcf' 

    def eliminate_vcard_duplicatesv2(abinfile, aboutfile):

        #we first convert the Adrees Book IN FILE into a list
        ablist=[]
        with open(abinfile) as source_file:
            ablist = list(vobject.readComponents(source_file))

        #we then serialize the list to expedite comparison process
        ablist_serial=[]
        for i in range(0, len(ablist)):
            ablist_serial.append(ablist[i].serialize())

        #then add each unique vcard's position from that list in a new list unless it's already there
        ablist_singletons=[]
        duplicates=0
        for i in range(1, len(ablist_serial)):
            if i % 1000 == 0:
                print "COMPUTED CARD:", i, "Number of duplicates: ", duplicates, "Current time:", datetime.datetime.now().time()
            jay=len(ablist_singletons)
            for j in reversed(range(0, jay)): #we do reversed because usually cards have duplicates nearby
                if ablist_serial[ablist_singletons[j]] == ablist_serial[i]:
                    duplicates += 1
                    break
                else:
                    jay += -1
            if jay == 0:
                ablist_singletons.append(i)

        print "Length of Original Vcard File: ", len(ablist)
        print "Length of Singleton Vcard File: ", len(ablist_singletons)
        print "Generating Singleton Vcard file and storing it in: ", aboutfile

        #and finally write the singularized list to the Adrees Book OUT FILE
        with open(aboutfile, 'w') as destination_file:
            for k in range(0, len(ablist_singletons)):
                destination_file.write(ablist_serial[ablist_singletons[k]])

    eliminate_vcard_duplicatesv2(abinfile, aboutfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on [Anthon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403636/3051142), using class decorators.

```py
import vobject
from vobject.base import Component, ContentLine


def sortedContents(cls):
    def getSortedChildren(self):
        return [obj for k in self.sortChildKeys() for obj in sorted(self.contents[k])]

    cls.getSortedChildren = getSortedChildren
    return cls


def sortableContent(cls):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return str(self) < str(other)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self) == str(other)

    cls.__lt__ = __lt__
    cls.__eq__ = __eq__
    return cls


Component = sortedContents(Component)
ContentLine = sortableContent(ContentLine)


addresses = set()

with open('infile.vcf') as infile:
    for vcard in vobject.readComponents(infile):
        addresses.add(vcard.serialize())

with open('outfile.vcf', 'wb') as outfile:
    for address in addresses:
        outfile.write(bytes(address, 'UTF-8'))
```